# Can I make the method dynamically called in Java?

Tags: java

for example, I have a variable called ("method"), it is a String, but I would like to do something like this....

```
obj.method(); //The object called the method();
```

But I would like to change the .method to a dynamic method, which means, I want to call the method base on the variable. For example, if I the I do something like this:

```
method = ".toString()";
```

Is there any method to help me to pass this string to the object, and the object will call the

```
obj.toString();
```

If the method is

```
method = ".toChar()";
```

I want it called the

```
obj.toChar();
```

How can I do so? Thank you.

Comment: you can (see answers), but you shouldn't, on a regular basis. Java is statically typed and you should use the benefits of this.

Answer (score 5):

You use the reflection API for this. In your case it would be something like this:

```
String method = "toString";
Class<Obj> objClass = obj.getClass();
Method m = objClass.getMethod(method);
m.invoke(obj);
```

It's untested but it should work. Otherwise just read a bit around in the documentation.

Note that this is often (but not always) the wrong way to do things in Java.

Comment: Glad you agree. In my experience especially beginners and people coming from dynamic languages tend to use reflection in inappropriate ways.

Answer (score 0):

Reflection is the way. Here is a [starting poin](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethods())t for you.

You may refer a tutorial [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/index.html).